# Missing files in axis2 download

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

Does anyone know anything about this?
Every simple SOAP web server tutorial I have found uses Axis2 from:

https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html

But I keep getting a 500 error that says files are missing.
I am missing the "include" folder with the jsp files in it. This folder is supposed to be located under Web Content > axis2-web

Here's a screenshot of one tutorial that actually shows what I seem to be missing from the apache download. By the way, I am downloading the binary zip and using Tomcat and Eclipse.

[click here to see the files that are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzYnX.png)